# Remove duplicate entries when it occurs more than twice

Tags: python, list, sequence

Suppose, I have a list below

```
list = [1,1,1,1,2,3,1,4,4,4,4,3,3]
```

I want to remove the duplicates which occur more than twice. Basically, I want like this

```
[1,1,2,3,4,4,3,3]
```

I use the following code

```
i = 0
while i < len(list) -2:
    if list[i] == list[i+2]:
        del list[i+2]
    else:
        i = i+2
```

this code gives me the following output

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3]
```

Here 4 occurs thrice, but I want twice. How can I modify the code or any other method that could give the desired output?

Comment: The short answer is to build a new list containing only the elements you want (and then you can throw away the old list).

Comment: @PedroMaia you are correct

Comment: You can also try

    lst = [1,1,1,1,2,3,1,4,4,4,4,3,3]
    
    result = []
    for i in lst:
        if result.count(i) < 2 or lst.count(i) % 4 == 3:
            result.append(i)

output:
 
`[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3]`

Comment: `[n for *p,n in zip([0,...]+lst,[1]+lst,lst) if [n,n]!=p]`  --> [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i = 2
while i < len(list):
    if list[i] == list[i-1] and list[i] == list[i-2]:
        del list[i]
    else:
        i += 1
print(list)
```

output :

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that if the 1 repeats again, it removes from the first entry. Say list = [1,1,1,1,2,3,1,4,4,4,4,3,3,1,1]. Applying your solution gives me [2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1]. But the output should be [1,1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1]

Comment: I have updated my answer. Just put i=2 at the begenning